# Symfony2 Form Display Alterations

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

As shown in the screenshot below, my form has fields for a exercise multiple times. (A user will do the exercise more than once). I want to customise the form, so only the first exercise select field of each particular exercise is shown. They cannot add additional sets and cannot change the exercises. The form elements are loaded in from a generic routine.

How would I go about doing this in Symfony2 and Twig?

Also, how would I take print the name of the exercise through the form element and not the select box?

[image: Screenshot]

I've currently got the following for displaying the form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{% for exercise in form.logExercises %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(exercise.exercise, 'Exercise', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(exercise.exercise) }}
        {{ form_widget(exercise.exercise, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        {{ form_label(exercise.weight, 'Weight', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(exercise.weight) }}
        {{ form_widget(exercise.weight, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        {{ form_label(exercise.repetitions, 'Reps', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(exercise.repetitions) }}
        {{ form_widget(exercise.repetitions, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{% endfor %}

<hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.note, 'Notes', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.note) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.note, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Save Session</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your Exercises are of the "entity" form field type? If not, you should consider it. Then you will be able to use a [custom query](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) where you can select only the topmost items of the grouped entities (group them by exercise type). Can't say more than this without seeing some additional code. Hope this helps, feel free to ask for details.